# FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKLoginKit from Firebase pod?: 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension)

Tags: xcode, firebase, cocoapods, ios-app-extension

I am trying to get my extension working with Firebase. For some reason, the FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit are being added and giving the "sharedApplication is unavailable" error. The thing is, I'm not even using those kits... I'd like to get rid of them, but I can't seem to find out how.

Based on SO advice, I have:

Deleted Podfile/podfile.lock/workspace/pods folder

Cleaned Cache

Ran Pod Install again

Closed Xcode

Cleaned Build Folder

Reran build

Same kits throwing me off, even though I'm not using them... just interested in Firebase Auth and Firestore. Relevant parts of my Podfile are below:

```
target 'MyNewProjectIntentTarget' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyNewProjectIntentTarget
pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Database'

end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There could be a lingering reference in the Xcode project. Try the following:

- `pod deintegrate`
- Make a back up copy of the Xcode project
- Open the Xcode project in an editor and remove any FBSDK references
- `pod install`